# Fetch api data with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, fetch-api

I'm new to reactjs, and I'm using create-react-app to get started, but I can't understand how make an api call to fetch data. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// import { URL, KEY, city, countryCode } from './config.json';


const KEY = "d7ba7d7818dd3cec9ace78f9ad55722e";
const URL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
const CITY = "Paris";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var url = `${URL}/weather?q=${CITY}&APPID=${KEY}&units=metric`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({data: json});
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The render method is just the default render from create-react-app, I didn't change it. I only added the constructor and componentDidMount methods.
I try to fetch some data from the OpenWeatherMap API, add it to the state and log it to the console.

The request works perfectly in postman, but raises this Error in my app:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include protocol with URL to resolve the problem. Response of fetch request is not success so when you try to parse response as JSON it throws exception because response it not valid JSON.

```js
const KEY = "d7ba7d7818dd3cec9ace78f9ad55722e";
// Made change here
const URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
const CITY = "Paris";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var url = `${URL}/weather?q=${CITY}&APPID=${KEY}&units=metric`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      json => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({data: json});
      }
    ).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```