# JSON parse error when fetching a local JSON file in an enviroment created by create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I am playing with the environment created by [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app). I am trying to fetch json data from a local json file, but I am getting the error message `SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"` In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081699/615274) I got to understand that I need to add a protocol but after adding it I am getting the same error. This is the component I am  trying

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Countries extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            countries: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/dataset.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }

    render() {
        const countries = this.state.countries;
        const rows = countries.map(country => (
            <Country name={country.name} code={country.code} />
        ));

        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function Country(props) {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{props.name}</td>
            <td>{props.code}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}

export default Countries;
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: Try to add the `dataset.json` to your `public` directly and just write `fetch("/dataset.json")` instead. Or you could leverage Webpack and just import the JSON file and make it into an object. `import dataset from "./path/to/dataset.json"`

Comment: yes, it is a valid json, I thought it was probable, and for that reason I tried a code with only javascript and the data is loaded properly

Comment: Thanks Tholle, moving the dataset file to public directory and change the fetch url to just `/dataset.json` did the job. Could you please develop the second method that you mention

Comment: @user615274 Create React App uses Webpack under the hood, which not only allows you to import JavaScript files with e.g. `import MyComponent from './MyComponent.js'`, but also JSON files. Try to move `dataset.json` to the same directory as your `Countries` component file and write `import dataset from './dataset.json'`, and you will get the data as an object directly in your file automatically in the `dataset` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Create React App everything in the `public` directory will be available at the root of your site, so you can move the `dataset.json` file there and just fetch `/dataset.json` instead.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("/dataset.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```