# JS Fetch returns HTML when given headers for 'application/json'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api, create-react-app

I have code for a fetch request of an API that I know returns JSON (see the node - https request below.) However, the response comes back as text/html even though I set the headers for 'application/json'. This doesn't make sense as all the manuals show my code as being correct. Not much out that delves into why I am getting back html.

JS FETCH

```
const submit = () => {
        const API_KEY = '4cb192e459db0f503de68ecd35c8fde4'
        // const CITY = 'paris'

    fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=${API_KEY}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(async response => {
        // response.json();

        console.log(response.text())
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

NODE HTTPS

```
const https = require('https')

const API_KEY = '4cb192e459db0f503de68ecd35c8fde4'

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
    port: 443,
    path: `/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=${API_KEY}`,
    method: 'GET'
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

I have even tried reading the response body as a readable stream, and still trying to understand this as the response does return a body.

For clarity I am getting a 200 response, basis response-type, and for the fetch the response is text/html. Of course the fetch gives me the typical error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch api data with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080730/fetch-api-data-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Create-React-App it routes the api request through the localhost. Adding Https:// to front of the api request fixed this issue.

See:

[Fetch api data with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080730/fetch-api-data-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

it's because when you use header on client, this header is for telling to server that "hi server im json" but by default server ordinarily response as (content-type: text/html), so you should specify that (content-type: application/json) in server too.